# I cant draw a circle at my players center position

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to add a circle at my players center position. However i can only see edge of the circle. Heres my code.

```
class Cavit(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((50,50))
        self.rad = 100
        self.image.fill((255,0,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = 100,100
        pg.draw.circle(self.image,(0,0,0),self.rect.center,self.rad,5)
        self.pos = vec(100,100)
        self.vel = vec(0,0)
        self.acc = vec(0,0)
        self.friction = 0.1
        self.playeracc = 0.8
```

And ı am sharing the picture so you can see the weirdness What i expect is. i want a circle with 100 radius that surrounds the rectangle .
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radius of the circle is half the size of the image. You need to find the center of the image rectangle before you set the center of the rectangle in the world:

```py
class Cavit(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((50,50))
        self.image.fill((255,0,0))

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rad = min(self.rect.width, self.rect.height) // 2
        pg.draw.circle(self.image, (0,0,0), self.rect.center, self.rad, 5)
        self.rect.center = 100, 100

        # [...]
```

Notice that you are drawing the circle on the image, not on the screen. Therefore, the center of the circle is the center of the image, but not the center of the image on the screen.

---

If the circle needs to be larger than the rectangle, the image needs to be the size of the circle:

```py
class Cavit(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        
        self.rad = 100
        
        self.image = pg.Surface((self.rad*2, self.rad*2), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        
        inner_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 50, 50)
        inner_rect.center = self.rect.center
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, (255, 0, 0), inner_rect)
        
        pg.draw.circle(self.image, (0,0,0), self.rect.center, self.rad, 5)

        self.rect.center = 100, 100

        # [...]
```

Comment: Yes now worked but this is not the way i want. I want a circle that surrounds the rectangle not the rectangle surounds the circle. This method surrounds the circle.

Comment: @omneer So you cannot do it like this. If you want to draw a circle on `self.image`, the circle cannot be larger than the image.

Comment: Alright so it is okay than, i think i could do this with adding a real image. Thanks for the help

Comment: @omneer I've extended the answer.